# How to set size of a checkbox in table vaadin

Tags: java, css, checkbox, vaadin

I have *column* that contains default vaadin checkbox in my **vaadin table**. My table width is 100%, I have also column that contains *embedded image* so the height of row is **90 px.**

**Vaadin version is 7.6.3.**

I want to set *height* and *width* of checkbox to about **60px**.

**How do I achieve that?**

*My java code*:

```
CheckBox cboxone=new CheckBox();
cboxone.setConvertedValue(true);
cboxone.setHeight("60px");
cboxone.setWidth("60px");
cboxone.setStyleName("csmy");
```

*I set height and width to 60px. I apply css style (style name is csmy) to checkbox. I try following css styles:*

```
  @import "../valo/valo.scss";

  @mixin blabla{
  @include valo; 

    //here i put my css styles
    
    .csmy .v-checkbox > label{
        
        height:60px !important;
        width:60px !important;
    }

    .csmy .v-checkbox{
        
        height:60px !important;
        width:60px !important;
    }

   .csmy{
      height:60px !important;
      width:60px !important;
   }

   .csmy .v-checkbox > input{
        
        height:60px !important;
        width:60px !important;
   }
}
```

But still nothing happen. Checkbox is still the same size as before.

Comment: Are you using the valo theme? If yes, then look at these https://demo.vaadin.com/valo-theme/#!checkboxes. When you inspect the SCSS rules, you can find out how to make even larger checkboxes

Comment: I am using valo theme. I inspect elements with mozzila firefox inspector and i try to find out the way to increase the elements size but it a bit tricky for vaadin checkbox. Why there is atribute height and width on checkbox if they are not effective, they don't increase size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the checkbox.scss of the valo theme you see this:

```
/**
 * Outputs the selectors and properties for the CheckBox component.
 *
 * @param {string} $primary-stylename (v-checkbox) - the primary style name for the selectors
 * @param {bool} $include-additional-styles - should the mixin output all the different style variations of the component
 *
 * @group checkbox
 */
@mixin valo-checkbox ($primary-stylename: v-checkbox, $include-additional-styles: contains($v-included-additional-styles, checkbox)) {

  .#{$primary-stylename} {
    @include valo-checkbox-style;
  }


  @if $include-additional-styles {
    .#{$primary-stylename}-small {
      @include valo-checkbox-style($unit-size: $v-unit-size--small);
      font-size: $v-font-size--small;
    }

    .#{$primary-stylename}-large {
      @include valo-checkbox-style($unit-size: $v-unit-size--large);
      font-size: $v-font-size--large;
    }
  }
}
```

You see the both variants large / small styles.
Basically it is using the `$v-font-size` value, so just define another checkbox style as `huge` for example and use your 60px size for the variable and it should work.

So in your theme scss file add these lines and use the style `huge`for your checkboxes

```
  $v-unit-size--huge: 60px;
  $v-font-size--huge: 60px;

  // Insert your own theme rules here
  .v-checkbox-huge {
  @include valo-checkbox-style($unit-size: $v-unit-size--huge);
      font-size: $v-font-size--huge;
    }
```

And in the java code:

```
    CheckBox cb1= new CheckBox();
    cb1.addStyleName("huge");
```

Comment: I have no clue how to achieve that, can you please give some additional explanation or example for my case. I am just used to add my css styles bellow @include valo;

Comment: @slodevelepor I added a real example in the answer

Comment: Tnx you very, very, very much.